# Regex not returning true

Tags: php, regex

I'm struggling to convert .htaccess rule into PHP regex if statement, here's the rule as it is in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ user.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Now for PHP I've tried several ways, as i'm not too good with REGEX nothing seems to work.

```
if(preg_match("#user\/(a-z_\-0-9)\$#",$request)) {
        exit("okKKKKKK");
    } else {
        exit("no");
    }
```

$request is "/user/test-user" anyone could give me a hand?

Comment: There's <del>nothing</del> little to translate, both Apache and preg_match() use a similar Perl-compatible regex flavour.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same regular expression you have in your `.htaccess`, just place a forward slash before *user*.

```
if (preg_match("#^/user/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$#", $request)) { ...
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/170192)

Answer (score 1):

That is not correct translation. Use this equivalent `preg_match` regex:

```
preg_match("#^/user/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$#", $request);
```

Remember rewrite rules in `.htaccess` have missing leading slash as `.htaccess` is per directory directive.

Answer (score 0):

It should be probably something like this

```
if(preg_match("#^\/user\/[a-z_\-0-9]+\$#i",$request)) {
  exit("okKKKKKK");
} else {
   exit("no");
}
```

In my opinion you should also track uppercase (i) modifier and make 301 redirects to lowercase url if user exists